# Scala: matching special characters

Tags: regex, scala

In Scala I need to test if a string has any of the following 'special' characters: `!@#\$^%&*()_-\+={}[]|;:"'<,>.?/`

I can not simply use `'nonword'` `"\\W"` regex for this because string may have Cyrillic characters that regex `"\\W"` matches as well. Trying to use regex:

```
new Regex("""~`!@#\$^%&*()_-\+={}[]|;:"'<,>.?/""")
```

results in exception:

```
 java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 17 ~`!@#\$^%&*()_-\+={}[]|;:"'<,>.?/
                                                                                           ^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:3104)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2101)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: put the all chars into character class. `[~!@#\\$^%&*\\(\\)_+=\\{\\}\\[\\]|;:\"'<,>.?-]`

Comment: Thanks, it works for all chars except for [` \ /] How to add these?

Comment: did you want to add space ` `? In the below answer, i added a forward slash and a backtick inside character class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put all the special characters into character class.

```
[~!@#$^%&*\\(\\)_+={}\\[\\]|;:\"'<,>.?`/\\\\-]
```

If you want to add space also, then it should be

```
[~!@#$^%&*\\(\\)_+={}\\[\\]|;:\"'<,>.?` /\\\\-]
```

Comment: You need to match the backslash as well, and some don't need escaped. ``[-~!@#$^%&*()_+={}\\[\\]|;:\"'`<,>.?/\\\\]``

Comment: @hwnd: Thanks! That covered all of them!